# Throw custom exception from Spring controller and receive it in ajax-post error function

Tags: ajax, spring, error-handling

So, i need to add custom validation to my page, the problem is, i don't have any form, i collect and send data almost manually, here is my ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/settings/propertyedit",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    data: {
            propertyName : propName,
            propertyValue : propVal,
            Id : Id,
            SettingId : SettingId,
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader($.metaCsrfHeader,  $.metaCsrfToken);
    },
    success: function (response) {
        //Do some something good
    },
    error: function(response){
        //do some something worning
    }
});
```

And controller:

```
@Link(label = "property edit", family = "SettingsController", parent = "Settings")
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings/propertyedit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String atmpropertyedit(@RequestParam String propertyName,
                              @RequestParam String propertyValue,
                              @RequestParam Long Id,
                              @RequestParam Long SettingId) {
    //Check if it is an error
    //If correct i want to return some text in success function
    //If error happens want to return some relevant text to error function
}
```

So, the point is, that validation is also custom, so i cant throw exception simply with try catch and if i am trying to do something like:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_EXTENDED);//Error type is for testing purposes
```

I will get 400 error even without triggering into my controller. At this point i just want some simple method to let know my ajax what has happened in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

The controller can be as simple as this one, you can make it happen with custom response class which I named `CommonResp` and an Enum `VALIDATION`.

**Controller** - returns Response class.

```
@ResponseBody
public CommonResp atmpropertyedit(@RequestParam String propertyName,
                              @RequestParam String propertyValue,
                              @RequestParam Long Id,
                              @RequestParam Long SettingId) {


        // error
        if (!isValidPropertyName(propertyName)) return new CommonResp(VALIDATION.INVALID_PROPERTY_NAME);

        // success
        return new CommonResp(VALIDATION.OK);
    }
}
```

**CommonResp.java** - will be the json response.

```
public class CommonResp implements Serializable {

   private int code;
   private String message;

   public CommonResp() {
       this(VALIDATION.OK);
   }

   private CommonResp(final int code, final String message){
       this.code = code;
       this.message = message;
   }

   public CommonResp(VALIDATION validation) {
       this(validation.getCode(), validation.getMessage());
   }

    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

**VALIDATION.java**

```
public enum VALIDATION {

    OK(200, "OK"),
    INVALID_PROPERTY_NAME(401, "PropertyName is not valid");

    private int code;
    private  String message;

    private VALIDATION(int code, String message) {
        this.setCode(code);
        this.message = message;
    }

    /* Getters and Setters */

}
```

Please let me know if there are any better implementations. (propably tons of, It's just that i don't know :P)